# search a string in textbox from a source code file in c#

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, search, substring

I'm a newbie to here. and i don't have any expirience in coding.I was stuck in coding part of my project.I have done it in C# in visual studio

I wanted to search a string typed in text box in a file that is open as another string which is a source code. And i wanted to check the typed string is there before a 20 characters in front of the word "$_POST" which is in the source code.and if the string is there, print something. I have attached the code until i have done.Please help me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace XSS_Prevention_Tool
{
    public partial class Home : Form
    {
        int count = 0,lc=0;
        string language;

        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            languageSelection();
            folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            txtpath.Text= folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.ToString();
            ColumnHeader header1 = new ColumnHeader();
            header1.Text = " Scanning: ";
            header1.Width = listFiles.ClientSize.Width;
            listFiles.Columns.Add(header1);
            DirSearch(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.ToString());
        }

        private void languageSelection()
        {
            if (rdoASP.Checked == true)
            {
                language = "asp";
            }
            else if (rdoJSP.Checked == true)
                language = "jsp";
            else if (rdoPHP.Checked == true)
                language = "php";
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Select a language");
            lblLanguage.Text = language;
            textBox2.Visible = true;
        }

        public void DirSearch(string dir)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
                {
                    string e = Path.GetExtension(f);
                    if (e == "."+language)
                    {
                        listFiles.Items.Add(f);
                        lc++;
                        textBox2.Text = lc.ToString();
                        XSS(f);
                    }
                    count++;
                    textBox1.Text = count.ToString();
                }
                foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
                {
                    DirSearch(d);
                }

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void XSS(string f)
        {
            String methode = "$_POST";
            System.IO.StreamReader myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(f);
            string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();

            myFile.Close();
            if (myString.Contains(methode))
            {
                int pos = myString.IndexOf(methode);
                MessageBox.Show(pos.ToString());
            }


        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void listFiles_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txtpath_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what your question is exactly about. What error do you see?

Comment: Does your code compile?  If not, what errors are reported?  Does it run?  If not, what exceptions are thrown, or what other unexpected behavior is exhibited?  Are the results incorrect?  If so, what is the expected result, and what is the actual result?

Comment: _[Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_ **and** _[Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))_

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I just wanted to know any solutions are there. This code is working but some more coding is needed. That was I asking. To get a value from a textbox and search it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need to find the substring within a string. Just go through these examples and try to find a solution.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring

Substring in C# string Class returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified given index and extended up to the given length.

string string.substring(int startIndex,int length)

Parameters:

startIndex: The index of the start of the substring.

length: The number of characters in the substring.

Returns:

The specified substring.

Exceptions:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : the beginIndex or length less than zero, or the begin index + length not within the specified string

Comment: Thanks BSG, glad at least one understood my question. I'll try. Also can u tell me how to search it from a textbox

Comment: store textbox.Text value in a string and you can use this string for search.   string s = textBox1.text;

Comment: If you think any of the solution provided by stack overflow members is useful to you please upvote the solution and if the solution works please accept the answer. Thanks BSG.